# how to change menu titles

Tags: menus, headers

At the top of this website Wordpress answers is 6 menu items in the header
`Questions`   `Tags`    `Users`   `Badges`   `Unanswered`    `Ask Question`
I need to change these on my website [homesfriscotx.com](http://homesfriscotx.com)       how do I do it?

Thanks,
Debbie

Answer (score 1):

The implementation of menu items depends on your theme.

For newer or well maintained and updated theme it is usually implementation of [Custom Menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel) feature. For the rest it could be anything from auto-generated list of pages to custom theme settings page in admin.

Answer (score 0):

http://en.support.wordpress.com/menus/ - 1st result from google for "wordpress menus"